# Tax-Savvy Pre-Retirement Liquidity Cushion, or IRS Surprise? -using put options and an IRA

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira, put-options

I have 300 shares in a regular account with basis 166, trading @ 500. I have over 300 shares of the same in an IRA. I plan to sell 300 shares in the IRA; write 3 puts in the IRA for less than $10,000 total credit (the rounded up total of the asks minus some % of the bid-ask spread); and buy the same 3 puts in the regular account for ~$10,000 debit. The expiration dates are spread out over three years, I.e., January of year 1, Jan. year 2, and Jan. Yr. 3.

My question is basically how the weird, offsetting put positions are treated. I assume if this is a bad idea, it's because of complicated tax law regarding offsetting positions, and that’s what I’m hoping somebody can answer to, but I will accept any good criticism or support you have of the idea if it’s relevant and verifiably accurate. I also welcome alternative ideas, but they are off topic if they don’t address why not to do this one.

Here’s how the idea came to be:

I hold 300 shares in my taxable account, worth $500 each. I’m aiming to turn this into a cash cushion to fund a three-year break from work by selling them for $150,000. That’s $50,000 per year.

I fear a hefty tax bill due to this year’s work earnings. So, Instead of selling them, I bought put options to hedge against stock drops.
The put expirations are spread out over three years.

Looking for ways to offset the cost of the puts, I think of writing put contracts in my Roth IRA (among other things like just writing calls.) Writing the puts seems like a bad idea at first because it mathematically removes the hedge on the shares. But then, with the IRA in mind, I realized that I don’t need a hedge on the shares if I just sell. If I’m worried about taxes of creating a large cash cushion in one tax year now, why not just sell $150,000 worth of shares in the IRA instead of the taxable account? The obvious answer is that I’m not retirement age and so I don’t have access to the funds if I do that. But the short put positions in the IRA and long put positions in the taxable account create an interesting situation if they are the exact same contracts and were opened at the money.

At expiration, if the market is down, I exercise the contract in the taxable account, getting $50k as planned. I get assigned In the IRA, forcing me to buy back shares at the sale price. So I’m good there.

If the market is up, the taxable account gains, offsetting the put cost. I can sell $50,000 worth of shares as planned. The IRA puts will expire worthless, and I won’t be able to buy as many shares back as it sold due to the price going up, but I don’t mind that scenario at all because it’s offset by not needing to sell as many shares as planned in the taxable account.

This approach spreads taxes, potentially shifts wealth from the IRA to the taxable in a manner that is attractive to me, and limits risk where I want it to at the expense and addition of risk where they are not problems for me.

I don’t see a downside. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think you can sell short in an IRA.

Comment: The rule is that you can’t use IRA assets as collateral for a loan, so you can’t short stocks, which is technically borrowing. What I meant is write a put, also referred to as selling to open a short put position. You can write puts in an IRA if you hold enough cash to cover the full risk of the position (I.e. the strike price times 100 shares.) That’s why I propose the idea to sell the shares in the IRA instead of the taxable account, and use the proceeds to secure short put positions.

Comment: Anything you do in the IRA has to stay in the IRA, and should have no effect on your taxes until you are taking money out of the IRA. So I'm not sure I'm seeing what you're accomplishing here. Yes. I use a single strategy across both buckets, but I'm not trying to do weird counterbalancing moves.

Comment: Not true. Moves made in an IRA can affect taxes. The wash sale rule is one example. What I’m accomplishing is solving a problem that I tried to explain. I have $150k of value in stock and I want it to hold its value over 3 years. Stocks are not known for being very good at that. So, I need to sell. But that will cause a large tax bill this year. If I sell over three years, I subject myself to market risk. Buying the puts solves that problem, but costs $10k. Selling the puts offsets the $10k debit. Problem solved! Can I accomplish the same without “weird” moves?

Comment: wash sales do not apply in an IRA because you can't claim a loss. You may have trades that are _classified_ as a possible wash sale just because of the timing but they have absolutely no effect on taxes.

Comment: You can not give up risk without giving up return. If your concern is not ever losing value, you don't belong in the stock market; higher-interest banking products, which have government insurance, are the way to get that safety.

Comment: The wash sale rule can indeed be triggered by a transaction in an Individual Retirement Account (IRA) and impact a taxable account. https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-drop/rr-08-05.pdf  ISSUE
If an individual sells stock or securities for a loss and causes his or her individual
retirement account or Roth IRA to purchase substantially identical stock or securities within 30 days before or after the sale, is the loss on the sale of the stock or securities disallowed?  HOLDING
The loss on the Sale of stock is disallowed under § 1091.

Comment: “You can not give up risk without giving up return”
True, but irrelevant! I’m not attempting to get return; That’s done. It’s a tax strategy. I’m selling shares. That’s step 1. Risk gone. Return realized. Step 2: Put positions. They are net neutral. No added risk or potential for return. The key is how the strategy is spread across accounts such that the return is realized now, tax free, but then exchanged for shares with the taxable account evenly over the next 3 years at tax-favorable times set by the contracts instead of one giant taxable event this year.

Comment: @keshlam - **If your concern is not ever losing value, you don't belong in the stock market.**  Apart from being harsh and uncalled for, limiting risk while locking in the majority of the gain and retaining profit potential is a viable strategy.

Comment: I said **ever**. Liming risk is certainly possible, though usually at the expense of limiting growth. But if the goal is to completely eliminate risk, the market really is the wrong place to have your money. Part of investing is being able to accept that paper losses are generally not something to panic about, or even necessarily to take action about. Not everyone is comfortable with that, and there's nothing wrong with picking any point along the spectrum that you are comfortable with as long as you understand what to expect and are OK with it happening.

Comment: All of keslem’s comments are true but based on the assumption that I am trying to get something for nothing, arguing with that erroneous misconstrual instead of what is actually proposed, an investment position result equivalent to selling shares, eliminating market risk. Proceeds immediately, on day one, go into the FDIC insured IRA sweep account. There’s no way to achieve more gains; the taxable account can, but only at the IRA’s expense (why I’d use a Roth, BTW). All benefits are related solely to tax efficiency and liquidity.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy puts in one account and sell the exact same puts in another account, you have an offsetting position (short against the box).  Therefore, your long 300 shares remain unhedged.

You might consider a low/no cost wide long stock collar to protect yourself.  You'll have upside potential, and if the strike is high enough and you're assigned, the additional appreciation could pay the tax bill.  If share price craters, you're largely protected.  [Read this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mark-cubans-famous-trade-concentrated-stock-a-altimari-cfp-)

Comment: Thanks @Bob! Selling calls (creating a collar) offsets put costs. Still, I find value in the IRA short puts considering I’ll sell 300 IRA shares on day one. Keeping all 600 shares and adding a collar defers taxes and locks gains without paying put costs outright. My realization was that same goal is achieved by selling IRA shares and writing the offsetting puts. Selling calls would be a bonus, as would keeping the high end of the upside potential by not selling calls. So, I might sell calls, but only in addition to everything else using the IRA. Any reason that won’t work? That’s my question.

Comment: Thank you, @Bob, for alerting me to the “short against the box” position. I’ve heard that phrase before but never paid any mind to what it meant. Looking into it more I found that generally shorting against the box treats the short sale as a constructive sale, triggering capital gains tax. So now I want to know if my suggested plan triggers an immediate capital gains tax because that would blow up the whole idea, answering my question. “Am I missing some negative consequence?”

Comment: At this point, I have no idea what positions you're referring to because the multiple word descriptions are confusing.  It would be much easier to evaluate if you edited your question (or asked a new one) where you itemize the positions.  For example, [[I own 300 shares in my regular account with a cost basis of $50 that are trading at $100.  I plan to buy 3 Mar $100 puts for $18 each in my regular account and sell 3 Mar $100 puts for $18 each in my IRA account. ]]  That's crystal clear.

Comment: Thanks @Bob. I should update the question. I can see that I'm confusing, sorry. I'm talking about 300 shares in regular account w/ basis 166, trading @ 500. I have over 300 shares of the same in IRA. I plan to sell 300 shares in the IRA; write 3 puts in the IRA for less than $10,000 total credit (minus some % of the bid-ask spread); and buy the same 3 puts in the regular account for $10,000 debit. Expiration dates Jan '24, Jan '25, and Jan '26. Does that help? My question is basically how the weird, offsetting put positions are treated. I assume if this is a bad idea, it's b/c of tax law.

Comment: The IRA shares are irrelevant since they are tax sheltered.  If you sell 3 puts in the IRA and buy the same 3 puts in the regular account, they are offsetting positions.  Whatever one makes, the other loses. Therefore, the 300 long shares in the regular account are unhedged.

Comment: Ok how does that hurt me though @Bob? Unhedged means to me 300 shares face market risk. Is there more to what you ment than that? In not you're telling me to worry about price drop. So: price drops 80% to 100, stays there to Jan24 expiration: I exercise the put, collect $50,000 from 100 shares in regular account, just as planned. If I'm fine there. Am I screwed in the IRA? No: I get assigned, return the $50,000 cash I got from selling "irrelevant" shares on day 1, receive 100 shares back in the deal. So it’s a wash in the IRA. Where's the pain?

Comment: Again, it's the same problem of different actions in different posts.  You need to start afresh with a new question.  Here's my last stab at this.  Ignore all shares.  If you sell a put in one account and you buy it in another, you have an offsetting position.  No gain, no loss.  To wit, it's a $150 put and the stock drops to $100.  On put gains $50 and the other loses $50.  That's a wash, regardless of what other positions you hold.  So, tell me, what does doing this accomplish???